# Simulate press on a rubber button infrared remote control with a Raspberry Pi

Tags: integrated-circuit, raspberry-pi, infrared, remote-control

[image]

I'm stuck.

I'm trying to use a Raspberry Pi to simulate a button press on an infrared remote control that uses conductive rubber buttons in order to control/automate a toy with Python.

Really grateful if someone could explain if it is possible to solder a wire from the Rasberry Pi gpio and do the above or any other method that might work. Please point me where I should document myself more.

With my basic knowledge, I understand that the rubber button when pressed completes that specific button circuit, so I was wondering if I could just send a signal in the continuation of the circuit (where the contacts would have meet) to simulate that circuit.

I think it goes to the integrated chip on the back side where it is modulated into the infrared code.

Or maybe just send some data directly to the chip?

Another idea was to cut the infrared LED from the remote and attach it to the Pi, then brute force the the command codes with Python.

How do people hack these basic remotes?

Comment: There's an image upload button that lets you embed the picture in the post. That way we don't have to follow a link.

Comment: Since Raspberry Pi uses Linux, and Linux has LIRC framework for receiving and sending infrared data, simply get a device that can be used to receive the original remote data and send it, so you don't have to interface the remote.

Comment: Conductive rubber used. So touch make low resistance between pads. To connect it to had to use dry contact. Some kind of relay. By hacking you mean reversed engineering?

Comment: @Transistor edited

Comment: @Justme I have a IR receiver module, but had problems reading other remotes other than the one that it came with. I was wondering if it would be possible with a teensy board, since that has analog outputs

Comment: @user263983 by hacking, i meant modifying or making use of a design with external tools/means. I will search for those, not sure I get it if it's possible

Comment: Can you extract a schematic of the circuit and give us links to the manufacturer's datasheets of the integrated circuits? We would need that information to give you a definite answer. If you can't do that then you should just start trying different experiments.

Comment: The switch can be done with any analog switch or carefully designed Opto isolator.